# What will I see if launch a thing into a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, reference-frames, observers

Suppose that I launch a thing into a black hole from a secure distance, this black hole is secure at 2 meters and is floating over my yard, doesn't matter.

What will I see?

Will I see that the thing increases their speed and falls quickly into the hole?

Or will I see that the thing decreases their speed and falls slowly, every time more slowly?

Comment: The duplicate I've suggested explains how to calculate the velocity that you observe. If you don't think this answers your question shout and I'll reopen this.

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll see the object at first accelerate towards the hole (under gravity) and then slow more and more as it approaches the event horizon. It will asympotically freeze in place at the event horizon and then gradually shift redder and redder until it disappears.

This is assuming that the black hole is big enough that the acceleration is similar across the body. For small black holes the tidal effects would rip the object up because of the great difference in acceleration between the parts of the object that are closer to the black hole and those that are further away.